# Can I hardcode the Azure B2C User Flow URL?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C, I have several User Flows for (login, password reset, update telephone). One of my B2C Flows updates a Users Phone Number (UpdatePhoneUserFlow).

I want to link to this Flow directly in an email newsletter. Can I hardcode the URL that is presented when I test the Flow? I know the common suggestion is to create a proxy app that loads the new User Flow. I want to avoid creating any new Web Apps. What are the risks?

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is not *really* supported or recommended but is possible. You can open the Azure Portal for the B2C tenant and copy the 'run now' url but there are considerations for this.

1. You have no continuity between B2C and the webapp the user lands on, so they won't be signed in (unless implicit flow, and this is not recommended)
2. The url will be long and ugly and include policy name, client id, scope, response type, redirect uri, and other junk that the user may find suspicious or flagged as junk/phishing by mail filters (see below).
3. Once the 'run now' url is published you cannot change it, whereas if you went via a proxy it can be updated and users are unaffected (e.g., new policy, client id, or return url).

Run now:
https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/youtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_susi_or_sspr&client_id=youtguid&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Proxy: https://account.contoso.com/updatePhoneNumber

The proxy url is not only a nicer link to your users, but is flexible for future updates in business logic or flow for when a user wants to update their phone number.

Comment: Can I ask you - why is this not supported or recommended?

Comment: You don't generate a random `nonce` each request, your app won't accept the sign-in as it didn't initiate it if using auth code flow, and if using implicit there are security concerns and therefore is being omitted in the next [OAuth version](https://oauth.net/2.1/)

Comment: I don't think I need the nonce in this context. Thank you for your help.